# Determining most recent time stamp between two values with the same ID

Tags: sql, sql-server, greatest-n-per-group

When I use this code it will return all instances of the `Case ID` when `value` has either been `First Contact Resolution` or `Resolved` at some point in it's time stamp history. I need to isolate the most recent timestamp of either of the two for a given `caseid`.

```
SELECT
        MAX(DATEADD(hh,-30,timestamp)) [Time Stamp],
        caseid [Case ID],
        value [Value]
        FROM
            svb_caseupdate
        WHERE
            DATEADD(hh,-7,timestamp) >= DATEADD(day,-30,GETDATE())
            AND value IN ('First Contact Resolution','Resolved')
GROUP BY caseid, value
```

For example, if both `Resolved` and `First Contact Resolution` exist in the time stamp history it returns both values, however I need it to return the most recent of either of the two.

| Case ID | Time Stamp | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| E575E0B7-C036-EE11-BDF4-6045BD006016 | 2023-08-09 09:56:02.000 | First Contact Resolution |
| E575E0B7-C036-EE11-BDF4-6045BD006016 | 2023-07-19 11:09:23.000 | Resolved |

The result should be:

| Case ID | Time Stamp | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| E575E0B7-C036-EE11-BDF4-6045BD006016 | 2023-08-09 09:56:02.000 | First Contact Resolution |